# Errors when trying to use jimp node module ionic v2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript-typings

I'm trying to import the jimp node module into my ionic 2 application and am having runtime errors. I have installed the typings for jimp and have compiled and ran the following code.

here is the typescript where I simply create a function to test Jimp

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LogInPage } from '../log-in/log-in';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
import * as jimp from "jimp";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  displayLogin() {
    this.navCtrl.push(LogInPage);
  }

  displayRegister() {
    this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
  }

  testJimp() {
    jimp.read("pic.png", function (err, pic) {
      if (err) throw err;
      pic.invert();
      pic.write("inverted.png");
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the html to call the function

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      myApp
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h1>myApp</h1>
  <button ion-button (click)="testJimp()">testJimp</button>
</ion-content>
```

I get the following runtime error when I click the testJimp button

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at module.exports (main.js:202298:5)
at getMIMEFromPath (main.js:172965:5)
at new Jimp (main.js:172900:9)
at main.js:172940:23
at new t (polyfills.js:3:11329)
at Function.Jimp.read (main.js:172932:19)
at HomePage.testJimp (main.js:79089:51)
at DebugAppView.View_HomePage0.handleEvent_25 (/AppModule/HomePage/component.ngfactory.js:310:34)
at DebugAppView.<anonymous>(main.js:126150:37)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:55299:36)
at s (polyfills.js:3:4211)
at new t (polyfills.js:3:11355)
at Function.Jimp.read (main.js:172932:19)
at HomePage.testJimp (main.js:79089:51)
at DebugAppView.View_HomePage0.handleEvent_25 (component.ngfactory.js:310:34)
at DebugAppView.<anonymous> (main.js:126150:37)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:55299:36)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3:9723)
at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (main.js:53370:37)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3:9697)
```

I've tried debugging the app and it breaks when trying to execute Jimp.read. I have also tried importing the code without typscript definitions following a guide online but had no luck. I'm new to javascript and typescript and am not sure where to go from here.